# How to Sum up number of list

Tags: python, list, sum

I want to sum up a total number of list from a nested list.

```
datalist = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], [['b', 'd', 'a', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']], ['a', 'b', 'g', 'h'], [['x', 'z', 'c', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'b', 'a']]]
```

**Sum of list is 6**

**Approach 1**

Gives me 4

```
print sum(1 for x in datalist if isinstance(x, list))
# 4
```

**Approach 2**

Gives me 8

```
def count_list(l):
    count = 0
    for e in l:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            count = count + 1 + count_list(e)
    return count

print count_list(datalist)
#8
```

**How can I sum up the number of list?**

Comment: Because you do have four lists. Two of those list themselves contain lists, though.

Comment: Two `list`s inside one `list` still count as 1. You can write a recursive method to count inner lists.

Comment: There are nested lists. Can there be multiple level of nesting as well?

Comment: maybe use `pprint.pprint(datalist)` to see the nested layers.

Comment: this shouldn't be marked as duplicated. the market duplicated post doesn't give the desired solution to OP's question.

Comment: @Kasramvd - I don't get exact solution from existing post!

Comment: @MysticCode You can use them as a hint. Note that you need to also check if the list doesn't contain any list then you want to count it.

Comment: @Kasramvd it's ok to mark a duplicate when it doesn't give a real solution to OP's problem? The duplicate definition states that it's a *exact duplicate of an existing question* when it's not in this case...

Comment: @Borja No it's not but it can be done with a simple change, and it would also be a good practice for OP. And that's what Stackoverflow is for :-)

Comment: So why you don't mark it as *un*duplicate?

Comment: You can convert your list to string, after search a number of ']' , and soustract                          1                           >>>  str(datalist).count(']')-1

Comment: >>> str(datalist).count(']')-str(datalist).count(']]') - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working flow :

```
>>> def count(local_list):
...     sum1 = 0
...     for l in local_list:
...             if not isinstance(l,list):
...                     return 1 
...             else:
...                     sum1+= count(l) 
...     
...     return sum1
... 
>>> count([['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], [['b', 'd', 'a', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']], ['a', 'b', 'g', 'h'], [['x', 'z', 'c', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'b', 'a']]])
6
```

Comment: @MysticCode you can accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve solution without recursive function?

Comment: There might be...will have to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do this with some recursion, as you've already shown in one of your functions

The function only adds 1 to `count` if the item is a `list` and the item does not contain any lists. Else, the function is called on the item again, recursively.

```
datalist = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], [['b', 'd', 'a', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']], ['a', 'b', 'g', 'h'], [['x', 'z', 'c', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'b', 'a']]]

def count_nested_lists(lst):
    count = 0
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            if not any(isinstance(l, list) for l in item):
                count += 1
            else:
                count += count_nested_lists(item)
    return count

print(count_nested_lists(datalist))
# 6
```